# Python: Building Matrix by element wise operations on numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Given two numpy arrays (arr1 and arr2) I want to build a matrix that stores the difference of each element in arr1 with each element in arr2. ie:

```
my_matrix = [arr1-i for i in arr2]
```

However this starts to get slow as the arrays get larger in size. I've tried to make use of numpy's good performance like so:

```
arr1_mtx = np.array([arr1]*len(arr2))
arr2_mtx = np.array([arr1]*len(arr2)).T
my_matrix = arr1_mtx-arr2_mtx
```

I'm quite new to Python so I'm not sure if this is the most pythonic and efficient way to build this matrix. Any tips?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "Given two lists(numpy arrays)" - NumPy arrays and lists are completely different things.

Comment: Good point. Let me edit that

Answer (score 0):

You can reshape one of the arrays to a 2d array, then make use of numpy [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html):

```
arr1[:,None] - arr2
```

---

```
arr1 = np.array([1,2])
arr2 = np.array([3,4,5])
​
arr1[:,None] - arr2
#array([[-2, -3, -4],
#       [-1, -2, -3]])
```